# How to add the column names to each pandas values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I add the pandas column's names to each value inside the rows?, for example, lets say I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
COL1     COL2      COL3     COL4 ...   COL_N
True      NO       90.9      2   ...  2018-05-17 20:14:00
True      NO       89.11     2   ...  2018-05-17 20:15:32

                    ............

True      NO       67.89     1   ...  2018-05-17 20:18:45
```

How can I turn it into:

```
COL1          COL2         COL3          COL4 ...   COL_N
True (COL1)    NO (COL2)    90.9 (COL3)   2 (COL4)   ...  2018-05-17 20:14:00 (COL_N)
True (COL1)    NO (COL2)    89.11 (COL3)  2 (COL4)  ...  2018-05-17 20:15:32 (COL_N)

                    ............

True (COL1)    NO (COL2)    67.89 (COL3)  1 (COL4)  ...  2018-05-17 20:18:45 (COL_N)
```

I want to do this because im analyzing some patterns inside each rows. One of the issues is that I am dealing with a large pandas dataframe (500x100000) columns. Any idea of how given a pandas data frame attach its column names to each values?

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem

Comment: That is extremely inefficient as you now would convert numeric columns to object (string) which store more space and don't allow the same nice vectorization. Maybe you should question your reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use :

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x+' '+x.name)
Out[7]: 
        COL1     COL2        COL3    COL4
0  True COL1  NO COL2   90.9 COL3  2 COL4
1  True COL1  NO COL2  89.11 COL3  2 COL4
```

Comment: thanks I was having issues with the types... I didnt know that I could do astype(str)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to loop the columns and use loc.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[:,col] = df[col].astype(str) + ' ({})'.format(col)
```